# React in HTML Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to work React into my HTML page which I'm trying to create dynamic cards from bootstrap, but I keep getting
Here's what I have so far

service.html

```
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="services-load"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>

  <script type="module" src="rjs.js"></script>
</body>
```

rjs.js

```
const e = React.createElement;
import Card from "./services/Cards";

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#services-load');
ReactDOM.render(e(<Card />), domContainer);
```

Cards.js

```
import Card from "./CardUI";
import img1 from "../assets/imgs/services/botox.jpg";
import img2 from "../assets/imgs/services/lipo.jpg";
import img3 from "../assets/imgs/services/prp.jpg";

const Card = props => {
  return (
    <div className="container aesthetic-body">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
          <Card imgsrc={img1}/>
        </div>
        <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
          <Card imgsrc={img2}/>
        </div>
        <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
          <Card imgsrc={img3}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Card;
```

CardUI.js

```
const Card = props => {
  return (
    <div className="card">
        <a href="">
          <div className="card-header">BOTOX / FILLERS</div>
          <img className="card-img-top" src={props.imgsrc} alt={"Card image cap"}/>
        </a>
      </div>
  );
}

export default Card;
```

**Update:**
Here's My file structure
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to work with `import`, you need to add a plugin for transforming `transform-es2015-modules-umd` by specify the `plugins` on `<script />`.

Let's imagine you have a following structure:

```
public
 - foo.js
 - index.js
 - index.html
```

`foo.js` exports an simple component like this:

```js
export default () => <div>Foo</div>;
```

`index.js` is all about importing and boostrap:

```js
import Foo from "foo";

ReactDOM.render(<Foo />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Finally, register modules in `index.html`:

```
<script
  data-plugins="transform-es2015-modules-umd"
  type="text/babel"
  src="./foo.js"
></script>
<script
  data-plugins="transform-es2015-modules-umd"
  type="text/babel"
  src="./index.js"
></script>
</body>
```

Here is full code in `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>

    <title>React App</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script
      data-plugins="transform-es2015-modules-umd"
      type="text/babel"
      src="./foo.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      data-plugins="transform-es2015-modules-umd"
      type="text/babel"
      src="./index.js"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also the codesanbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-bird-vwn5t?file=/public/index.js

Comment: hello I'm getting Uncaught Error: Invalid plugin specified in Babel options: "transform-es2015-modules-umd"
I've installed npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-umd
but still nothing

Comment: You don’t need to install anything, you just copy and run code via the browser

Comment: If you are not keen to browser anymore, you can simply switch to webpack which is quite easy for configuration. I thought you’re interested in playing with browser :)

Comment: Thank you for that! But im still getting the invalid plugin. I saw your package.json file and mine looks different. Sorry I'm still learning how to use react thank you for baring with me.
  "name": "clinic45",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "rjs.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "webpack-cdn-plugin": "^3.3.1"
  }
}

Comment: I’m not sure I’m guessing right. Do you mean you don’t know how to configure webpack?

Comment: Honestly all of this is new to me Babel and Webpacks. I've been reading through their guides all day. still can work around the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221048/discussion-between-tmhao2005-and-ljdayekh).

Comment: If you're keen to webpack, I can drop you an minimal configuration you need to run your code. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes! I replied back to you on the chat. I'm interested in seeing how webpack works

Answer (score 0):

You can't write HTML on js file. you need to switch to jsx ( Javascript XML ) file format.

Rename your files to `Cards.js => Cards.jsx` and `CardUI.js => CardUI.jsx`

Comment: I did that before and did it now again same error :/

Comment: please follow proper document of converting babel code to pure javascript

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a babel transpiler to translate the JSX syntax.

https://babeljs.io/

for react : https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react

Comment: I'm using this <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script> shouldn't that translate?

Comment: it should translate but not for standalone react components like CardUI.jsx or CardUI.js. so you need babel to translate CardUI.js

You can view it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#add-jsx-to-a-project